# Why Point() takes no argument is showing?

Tags: python, constructor

```
class Point:
    def _init_(self, x, y):  #A Constructor is being made here
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        print("Draw")

    def move(self):
        print("Move")


point = Point(10, 50)  # Is their any error in this line.
point.x = 12  # I am trying to update value of x.
print(point.x)
```

Comment: You misspelled `__init__` (there are two underscores before and after the name, not one). As a result, `Point._init_` is never called, but `object.__init__` *is* with two unexpected arguments, `10` and `50`.

Comment: Thank You Man!!!!!!!!!!
I am learning Python myself..
You really saved me..
Love Youuuu